# Indirect modification of overloaded property WP_Post::$classes has no effect

Tags: menus, child-theme, walker, post-class

I'm working on a child theme and while everything works the `Walker_Nav_Menu` and `Walker` classes are causing all the fuss. My parent theme overrides `Walker_Nav_Menu` as below:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Zen_Menu_Walker' ) ) {

class Zen_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output ) {
        $element->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->ID ] );
        $element->classes[]    = ( $element->current || $element->current_item_ancestor ) ? 'active' : '';
        $element->classes[]    = ( $element->has_children && 1 !== $max_depth ) ? 'has-dropdown' : '';

        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';

        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                //$value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "\n<ul class=\"sub-menu dropdown\">\n";
    }

}
}
```

This works without any fatal errors in parent theme. But inside child theme it produces fatal error:

`Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property WP_Post::$classes has no effect in /srv/www/htdocs/wpsite/wp-content/themes/zen-theme/class.menu.php on line 45`

Did some digging on **Stackoverflow** and **Google** and the only references I found were:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421661/getting-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-has-no-effect-notice
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454779/php-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053269/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-splfixedarray-has-no-effect
- https://gist.github.com/awshout/3943026#gistcomment-676280

A buggy day indeed... I'm using PHP 5.6 and from what I read:

> "As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error. "

Any guesses why this is happening...

Answer (score 1):

If "line 45" is the one that starts with `$element->classes[]` in your `display_element` method then try something like this:

```
public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output ) {
    $element->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->ID ] );

    if ( ! isset( $element->classes ) ) {
        $element->classes = array();
    }

    $element->classes[]    = ( $element->current || $element->current_item_ancestor ) ? 'active' : '';
    $element->classes[]    = ( $element->has_children && 1 !== $max_depth ) ? 'has-dropdown' : '';        

    parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}
```

The problem may be that the `display_element` function receives an element that doesn't have that `classes` property set in which case you are trying to push data to an array that isn't referenced anywhere except that instance only.

EDIT: Also, why are you using the `display_element` function when you can insert those classes in the `start_el` function which itself gets called by `display_element` with that element passed to it?

Comment: Thanks. That did it and you're right about inserting them in `start_el`

Comment: @anithegregorian Good to hear that but you should mark the answer as accepted if that's the case.